# Make CURL requests in C#

Tags: c#, curl, cookies

I want to call some Curl requests using c#. I searched and saw some examples but they did not work for me. My commands are as follow:

Curl example for login:

```
curl -X GET \
--digest -u "<username>:<password>" http://<IP>/api/auth/login \
--cookie-jar <cookieFile>
```

The login result can be fetched with:

```
curl -X GET \
http://<IP>/api/auth/user --cookie <cookieFile>
```

After that, data can be fetched for example with:

```
curl -X POST \
--data "{\"filter\" : [ { \"Name\" : \"ID\", \"Op\" : \"=\", \"Value\" : \"1\" } ], \
\"count\" : 1, \"offset\" : 0, \"brief\" : true, \"includeResultsetSize\" : false }" \
http://<IP>/api/$/database/getCrossings --cookie <cookieFile>
```

How can I call these commands using c#?

This is my example code which do not work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.5.204/api/auth/login");
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Accept = "application/json";
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "pass");
    request.UserAgent = "curl/7.37.0";
    request.ContentType = "api/auth/login";

    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
    {}
```

I got runtime error on "GetRequestStream" function: "Cannot send a content-body with this verb-type."

Comment: See HttpClient, WebClient or HttpWebRequest classes...

Comment: Why on earth is this tagged as PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the content type.

```
 request.ContentType = "application/json";
```